Lower bound for Kullback–Leibler divergence between Bernoulli distributed random variables
Let $D(x, y)$ be the Kullback–Leibler divergence between Bernoulli distributed random variables, i. e. $D(x, y) = x \ln \frac{x}{y} + (1-x) \ln \frac{1-x}{1-y}$.
I've seen this lower bound for this value (on Wikipedia page about Chernoff bound):
$$
D(x, y) \ge \frac{(x-y)^2}{2y}, \; x \le y
$$ $$
D(x, y) \ge \frac{(x-y)^2}{2x}, \; x \ge y
$$
But I can't find a proof for than bound or prove it myself. Are these bounds even correct, and how can one prove them?

Fix a value of $x$, and consider $$ d_2(x\|y) :=  x \log \frac xy + (1-x) \log\frac{1-x}{1-y}.$$ I'll restrict attention to $x,y \in (0,1)$ - in the edge cases, where $d_2$ is either $0$ or $\infty$, and the inequalities are trivial.
Notice that $$ \partial_y d_2(x\|y) = -\frac{x}{y} + \frac{1-x}{1-y},\\ \partial^2_{yy} d_2(x\|y) = + \frac{x}{y^2} + \frac{1-x}{(1-y)^2}.$$ Now, assume that $0 < y \le x,$ and from the Lagrange form of Taylor's theorem, notice that $$ f(y) = f(x) + f'(x)(y-x) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(y-x)^2,$$ where $\xi \in [y,x]$. But notice that $f'(x) = 0$, and for any $\xi \le x,$ $$ f''(\xi) \ge \frac{x}{\xi^2} \ge \frac{1}{x},$$ and so the second bound in the question follows.

For the first bound, instead note that $$ \partial_{x} d_2(x\|y) =  \log {x} - \log {1-x}\\ \partial^2_{xx} d_2(x\|y) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{1-x}. $$
By exactly the same approach, using $g(x) := d_2(x\|y),$ we see that if $0 < \xi \le y,$ then $g''(\xi) \ge \frac{1}{\xi} \ge \frac{1}{y},$ from which you can recover the second inequality.
